# Extract/filter Splunk Query and for conditional logic

Tags: java, spring-boot, splunk

I use basic Splunk queries mostly, like

```
index=myIndexHere source="path/to/logs/app.log" "Keyword to Filter Query On Example"
```

My question is, I want to find logs that have a value called `"Time taken:"`. Ok, that's great - based on what I wrote above, I know how to do that. I get a bunch of search results back in Splunk, that is in a JSON-style (this is logging from my Java Spring Boot application), i.e.

```
Object state is { "key1": "value",
  "key2": "value",
  "key3": "value"
}, Time taken: 500 ms
```

So it's some format like that. How can I filter/extract the `"Time taken:" VALUE` (just the numeric portion) and do a simple logic condition like "`> 1000ms`" such that I only get search results back that are greater than 1000ms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is with the `rex` command.  `rex` extracts capture groups into fields which can then be processed with other SPL commands.

```
index=myIndexHere source="path/to/logs/app.log" "Keyword to Filter Query On Example" "Time taken"
| rex "Time Taken:\s(?<timeTaken>\d+)"
| where timeTaken > 1000
```

This query assumes the Time taken field is always milliseconds.  If it can change then the query becomes more complex.

Comment: looks like I don't get back any results. I don't think the REGEX is matching, since running the base query with "Time taken" returns what I posted above in my question, which is like JSON string log of the Object class, THEN near the end is has "Time taken". I don't think the regex matches

Comment: could it be the "ms" piece at the end of the digits?

Comment: Please post one or two results from the query `index=myIndexHere source="path/to/logs/app.log" "Keyword to Filter Query On Example" "Time taken"`

Comment: The "Keyword to filter query on example" is redundant right? because the filtering I want to happen is on the string "Time taken" (is what Im filtering on) . Anyway, a query result from the "Time taken" would exactly look like this below (see next comment below for clarity):

Comment: 0e685a643892 2021-06-04 20:24:32.267 INFO  randomGeneratedUUID=c786d054-e867-40d6-b876-39472135b2f1 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] com.mypackage.demo.MyMethod - request complete - Object ReferenceId is: null, Object Info is: class Employee {
    firstName: null
    lastName: null
    dateOfBirth: null
    postalCode: null
}, Time Taken : 3893 ms

Comment: I see the case is different in the comment.  I've modified my answer to compensate.

Comment: Thanks. Can you recommend any Splunk sources to better learn these tools/queries? do you only recommend splunk documentation? I will mark as best answer.

Comment: Anyone who uses Splunk should take the free Splunk Fundamentals 1 on-line course at https://www.splunk.com/en_us/training/free-courses/splunk-fundamentals-1.html .   Splunk docs are excellent, including the Search Tutorial at https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchTutorial/WelcometotheSearchTutorial

Comment: Thanks!   <3 <3  <3